# Calculate weight accumulation for each edge in directed graph (river network)

Tags: python, networkx

I have a shapefile of river network with attributes of stream order and weight (sum of trash associated with this stream). How to calculate an accumulation of weights downstream using python and networkx module?

I have looking for appropriate instrument in networkx, but hadn't found or maybe I have something misunderstood in references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem using algorithm Ancestors. It seems to work with nodes and return the set of nodes, which we can summarize. It is not very convinient, because we need to obtain weights from streams to nodes and then associate them back from nodes to streams. But it's really working.

```
import networkx as nx
import os
dir = r'd:\YandexDisk\Projects\Bali'
os.chdir(dir)
G = nx.read_shp(r'Rivers_network.shp')
nodes = nx.nodes(G)
edges = nx.edges(G)
total_dict = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'Total')
for node in nodes:
    ancestors = list(nx.ancestors(G, node))
    sum_weight = 0
    for coords in ancestors:
        for edge in edges:
            if tuple([edge[0][0], edge[0][1]]) == tuple([coords[0], coords[1]]):
                sum_weight += int(total_dict[edge])
    print(sum_weight)
    for edge in edges:
        if edge[0] == node:
            accum_edge = {edge: sum_weight}
            nx.set_edge_attributes(G, accum_edge, 'Accum')
nx.write_shp(G, dir)
```